# self-inflatable mat damaged valve socket where to get replacement

Tags: camping, sleeping, sleeping-pads

[image]

I am looking for this plastic base cs I lost it for my self inflatable mat

here is just valve https://www.openair.co.uk/camping-c11/thermarest-therm-a-rest-winglock-valve-repair-kit-p6229/s48371?cid=GBP&gclid=Cj0KCQjwu7OIBhCsARIsALxCUaODIaW3xZWDYPCa3Vm3Ni7wElsaBcwE6CnvrwUVW8UWQA_oK7SSu9saAnVIEALw_wcB.  but I don't know where I could by this plastic part for the valve

Comment: Welcome to outdoors.SE. Shopping advice is not well suited to the stackexchange format. A Q&A here is supposed to be of general, long-term interest. We have an explicit policy that "Recommendations for what item to purchase are off-topic" https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  and although that isn't quite what this question is, I think the same logic applies.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturer? They should be able to tell you if your part is sold separately and where to order it.

Answer (score 3):

Thermarest currently appears to just sells replacement valve cores on their website at https://www.thermarest.com/sleeping-pads/sleeping-pad-accessories.

[image]

In my pad, the plastic valve housing that you show in your picture is glued directly into the seam of the fabric, and does not look like a consumer-replaceable part.  If you've lost your valve housing, maybe you could send it to the manufacturer for repair or replacement.